# page not found in django 404

Tags: python, django

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dInlk.png)I need help to solve a page not found issue on  my code, so i created an app called pages inside which I created another folder named templates followed by the app name then i render the index html without issue but when I try to render the about.html file I get an error of page not found

This is the app(pages) urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('about/', views.about_view, name='about'),

]
```

then the views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def about_view(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/about.html')


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')
```

then projects url.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', include('pages.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),


]
```

so the main issue is that i can't render a new html file because when i try i get the page not found error

Comment: remove `path('about/', include('pages.urls'))` from projects url pattern

Comment: mhhabib i just tried it and it did not  work

Comment: add the full error message

Comment: click on the error message link to view the error message